# Get transpose from uneven numpy array and/or get average from uneven numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have a program that outputs numpy arrays that looks like for example:

```
[[a1, a2],
 [b1],
 [c1, c2, c3]]
```

Is there an elegant and python-way to turn this into this ?

```
[[a1, b1, c1],
 [a2, c2],
 [c3]]
```

This purpose of this is to get the sum/average over the columns that does not complain if some values are missing, so I am happy with something that can do this directly. Here is a example for you to copy past:

```
import numpy
test = numpy.array([
        numpy.array([3, 5]),
        numpy.array([3.4]),
        numpy.array([2.8, 5.3, 7.1])
])
```

Comment: Are you trying to shift elements upward to fill in gaps above them? If not, I'm not sure that I understand the logic of what you're trying to do.

Comment: I am trying to get the average from all first, second etc… elements of each array, independently of how many of them they are. I thought one solution would be to the get transformation detailed here, but I am happy to get anything that gets me to the average.

Comment: I think I've come up with a better alternative.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You lose all the benefits of numpy arrays when you start treating them as ragged lists. An alternative is to set empty/missing elements to NaN, and use the functions prefixed with "nan" in the numpy suite to compute your statistics. For example, [`mean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html) maps to [`nanmean`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html), [`sum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.sum.html) maps to [`nansum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nansum.html), etc (complete list [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/genindex.html#N)). This has the additional advantage that the order of the gaps does not matter.

If at all possible, have your program create a single array that looks like this:

```
test = np.array([
    [3.0, 5.0, np.nan],
    [3.4, np.nan, np.nan],
    [2.8, 5.3, 7.1]])
```

If not, here is a primitive attempt at converting the input:

```
def to_full(a):
    output = np.full((len(a), max(map(len, a))), np.nan)
    for i, row in enumerate(a):
        output[i, :len(row)] = row
    return output
```

Now computing the mean is trivial:

```
mean = np.nanmean(test, axis=0)
```

Comment: I do not know in advance the length of the arrays that come out of my program, thus the form of the array … but I think it is the simpler solution for what I am trying to do. Thanks :) Kasrâmvd's solution also works and also permits to inverse uneven arrays if required.

Answer (score 3):

Since you don't have a matrix you can't benefit from Numpy's vectorized functionalities. Instead you can use `itertools.zip_longest` and `filter` as following to get what you want:

```
In [13]: import numpy as np

In [14]: import numpy
    ...: test = np.array(
    ...: [np.array([3 , 5]),
    ...:         np.array([3.4]),
    ...:         np.array([2.8,5.3,7.1])])
    ...:         

In [15]: from itertools import zip_longest

In [16]: [np.fromiter(filter(bool, i), dtype=np.float) for i in zip_longest(*test)]
Out[16]: [array([3. , 3.4, 2.8]), array([5. , 5.3]), array([7.1])]
```

Note that using `bool` as the filtering function will eliminate items like 0 or empty string which their bool value is False.

If you're not sure that you might have such items in your array you can just use another list comprehension or a `lambda` function with `filter`.

```
[np.array([for i in sub if i is not None]) for sub in zip_longest(*test)]
```

You might also wanna take a look at the [`zip_longest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.zip_longest)'s roughly equivalent implementation so that (if possible) generate the desired result at the first place before returning that list.

Comment: That works for me (fortunately, no 0 orempty string should be outputted from my program), thank you ! It is quite a surprise that you would need to import a package from something to does not look like so hard from the outside.